# Opening Accounts from Dashboard in New Tab says URL No Longer Exists

Tags: lightning, dashboard, classic

Having an issue that has just started today out of nowhere

We have dashboards for various things, all working lovely, but if anything (Account/Opportunity/User etc) is opened in a new tab it says *URL No Longer Exists*. Same tab, works fine.

What I have noticed is the link itself is `company.lightning.force.com/s/detail/{accountID}`, which works when opened in the same tab. If opened in a new tab, it goes to `company.my.salesforce.com/s/detail/{accountID}` which returns *URL No Longer Exists* in classic.

Turn Off Salesforce Classic for Your Org switched on in Lightning Experience Transition Assistant, I've also spun up a sandbox to see if the enhanced domains would be an issue, and same in there...

Also thought this might be a browser issue, but I have tried it in Vivaldi in W11, and Firefox in Linux, same thing happens.

No issue in Lists or Reports, just Dashboards using standard objects.

I hope I explainned that okay!

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior in my dev org. While I investigate, can you confirm if you are using "Lightning Table" as the dashboard component? Thanks

Comment: Hey Swetha, yes I am.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a known issue.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000029ltWQAQ

No idea why it just started happening, but should apparently be sorted come this winter update.

Thanks Swetha for giving this a go, Salesforce is just being Salesforce...